# How can the integral of the sum of a geometric series apply for r=1

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Say you have the series $R(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, which is convergent for $x\in[-1,1]$

Then you differentiate: $R'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-(x^2)^n$

This is a geometric series, so you can find the sum $R'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Then you can integrate this from $0$ to $x$, for $x<1$,
 to get $R(x)=\arctan(x)$

Therefore $R(x) = \arctan(x)$

Now, somehow, this also applies for $x=\pm1$, despite that the sum of the geometric series didn't hold for $x\ge1$. Why can we say this?

Comment: Editet to be more specific and clearer :)

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking. This might help: Since the series $s=\sum_n {(-1)^n \over 2n+1}$ is (not absolutely) convergent, Abel's theorem shows that $R(x)$ converges to $\pm s$ as $x \to \pm 1$. Hence $R$ is defined and continuous on $[-1,1]$ and since it equals $\arctan$ on $(-1,1)$ it follows that they are equal at $\pm 1$.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that if $R$ is equal to $\arctan(x)$ on $(-1,1)$, and they both are continous, they also have to be equal at $x=\pm 1$. Thanks